# How to retrieve entire LDAP (AD) directory information using c-ldap API?

Tags: c, active-directory, ldap

I have written a c code using c-ldap api to retrieve all the users present in LDAP (AD) service. How do i get all the user details if my users are more than 1000. I know that AD service has a MaxPageSize limit of 1000 by default.

I do not want to change my MaxPageSize limit and retrieve the entire users information through my c-ldap program.

I analysed the scenario using Wireshark with ldap-admin tool which retrieves all the user information from any LDAP service even if the users are more than 1000, but unable to findout my requriement.

Any help will be very useful since i am a fresher working in a company and this is my first project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use the "page mode" control.

Look at the [RFC2696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2696)  and at [Microsoft's interpretation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223321.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Tony. But can you brief me how can i modify my search in program to make changes to the LDAP_PAGED_RESULT_OID_STRING parameter. I have gone through RFC 4511 and 2696, Still i an unable to set the thing :'-(

Comment: Look at the source for ldapsearch in the openLdap distribution... which can be downloaded from either your package manager, or from http://www.openldap.org/software/download/  That's what I used as a methodology source for a program at my former employer.  If developing on Microsoft, I'm sure they have there own version of those tools that you can refer to.